# How can I assign a value to a column as I'm using PROC EXPORT?

Tags: sas

```
%if %sysfunc(exist(working.__extra_nos__)) %then %do;
    proc export data=working.__extra_nos__
        dbms=oracle replace;
        password="&password.";
        tablename="sch.no_selection_&env_type.";
        url="&dburl.";
        username="&user.";
    run;
```

sch.no_selection_&env_type also has column called identifier, which isn't in `__extra_nos__` so I want to set it to &identifier as I export it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to access database DBMSs by LIBNAME rather than PROC EXPORT.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003113591.htm

```
libname mydblib oracle user=testuser password=testpass path=hrdept_002;
```

[adjust for your oracle installation details]

Then instead of export, you just create or modify a table using normal language (SQL or Data Step)...

```
proc sql;
create table mydblib.sch.no_selection_&env_type. as
  select *, "&identifier" as identifier from work.tempextras;
quit;
```

or

```
data mydblib.sch.no_selection_&env_type.;
set work.tempextras;
identifier="&identifier";
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset from your `__extra_nos__` and put the identifier in then. Then export that dataset.

```
 
data work.tempextras;
    set working.__extra_nos__;
    identifier = &identifier.;
run;


%if %sysfunc(exist(working.__extra_nos__)) %then %do;
    proc export data=work.tempextras;
        dbms=oracle replace;
        password="&password.";
        tablename="sch.no_selection_&env_type.";
        url="&dburl.";
        username="&user.";
    run;

proc datasets library = work; /*delete the temp dataset*/
    delete tempextras; 
run;
```